# How to set up asynchronous unit testing using expectations in xCode 6?

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, asynchronous, xcode6

What syntax do I use when I want to register an expectation for my asynchronous unit tests in xCode 6? There's nothing easily searchable on Google for this topic yet, and stuff that shows up is written in Swift. I'm looking for Objective-C example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found a nice blog post about it by Sean McCune:
[Asynchronous Testing With Xcode 6](http://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/asynchronous-testing-with-xcode-6/).

For Objective-C he puts an example like so:

```
- (void)testWebPageDownload
{
    XCTestExpectation *expectation =
        [self expectationWithDescription:@"High Expectations"];

    [self.pageLoader requestUrl:@"http://bignerdranch.com"
              completionHandler:^(NSString *page) {

        NSLog(@"The web page is %ld bytes long.", page.length);
        XCTAssert(page.length > 0);
        [expectation fulfill];
    }];

    [self waitForExpectationsWithTimeout:5.0 handler:^(NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Timeout Error: %@", error);
        }
    }];
}
```

I suggest reading his post for further explanation.

Comment: Wow! XCTExpectations are super-awesome :)